# How to prevent IntelliJ from generating a MANIFEST.MF that overrides the original one?

Tags: java, tomcat, intellij-idea, war, manifest

I'm using IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate 14 and I want to deploy a web project to a tomcat server within IntelliJ.

In the Project Settings -> Artifacts, I defined a "Web Application: Exploded" from my web project. In the output panel of this artifact I get META-INF folder of my web project along with other web resources.

When I started the tomcat server the first time, IntelliJ built and deployed the exploded war to tomcat and my web application worked just fine. But if I restart the server, I get an exception

```
java.io.IOException: invalid header field
```

I looked at the output of the exploded war and I found that IntelliJ generated somehow a MANIFEST.MF in META-INF that overrided the original file of my project. Moreover this generated MANIFEST was truncated which caused the invalid header field exception.

How can I prevent IntelliJ from generating the MANIFEST.MF or is there any way to make the generated MANIFEST valid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact the MANIFEST.MF is generated by the maven-war-plugin in a parent pom.

I can override the value of the generated MANIFEST.MF by configuring the archive of the war. documentation of the configuration: http://maven.apache.org/shared/maven-archiver/index.html.